# awk save value as variable

Tags: awk, variable, output

I use the command

```
varioutput=$(awk '{print $j}' OFS=, data/damper.test_temp1.csv)
```

because I want to extract the j th value of a line of many values seperated by , . But when I want to use $varioutput it gives me always the whole line.

What am I doing wrong?

Actually I want to use

```
for ((j=1; j<=20; j++)); do
         varioutput=$(awk -F, -v jj="$j" '{print $jj}'  data/damper.test_temp1.csv)
done
```

So I am quite confused now weather I should use it like above or not?
I get an error, but when I use it like

```
for ((j=1; j<=20; j++)); do
         varioutput=$(awk -F, '{print $j}'  data/damper.test_temp1.csv)
done
```

I still get the line.

Now the following was the solution

```
for ((j=1; j<=20; j++)); do
         varioutput=$(awk -F, -v k=$j '{print $k}'  data/damper.test_temp1.csv)
done
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re specifying the output field separator, not the input field separator; use this instead:

```
varioutput=$(awk -F, '{print $j}' data/damper.test_temp1.csv)
```

(or set `FS` instead of `OFS`).

I’m also assuming that `j` is a placeholder above, and that you’re replacing it statically with the appropriate value (for example, `print $4`).

---

To use another variable from script, you must pass it to `awk`

e.g. for `RANK` variable in shell

```
varioutput=$(awk -F, -v j=$RANK '{print $j}' data/damper.test_temp1.csv)
```

---

Generally speaking, if you start using AWK for small pieces of a script as in this example, it’s better to use AWK for more of the script.

Comment: @steeldriver I think `j` is a placeholder here, the real command would be `print $3` or something like that.

Comment: ah yes that makes sense

Comment: I add way to do it in case $j should be a real variable.